# estoy recién aprendiendo a programar en java, en blueJ y tengo crear un areglo que calcule la cantidad de divisores

Tags: bluej

```
intente crear un arreglo que cuente la cantidad de divisores pero tengo problemas en el codigo de cantidad de divisores.

    private int[] vector;
    private int tamano;
    public maquinaVectores()
    {
        
    }
```

en esta parte el programa pide el tamaño del vector y los numeros.

```
 public void cargarVector()
       {
            int indice;
            Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("ingrese tamano del vector");
            tamano=leer.nextInt();
            vector= new int[tamano];
            for(indice=0;indice<tamano;indice++)
            {
                System.out.println("ingrese un dato para el vector");
                vector[indice]=leer.nextInt();
            }
             System.out.println("cargado finalizado");
       }
                     
    
               > en esta parte el programa pide el tamaño del vector y los numeros imprimiendolos en pantalla
```

** Esto es un codigo en bluej**           
2. Esto es un elemento de un arreglo                        
en esta parte final es la que tengo problemas.               
con el código al tratar de encontrar la cantidad divisores.

```
 public int calcularCantidadDivisores()
       {
           int residuo, canDiv, indice;
           canDiv=0;
           for(indice=1;indice<=vector[indice];indice++)
            {
                residuo= tamano%vector[indice];
                if(residuo==0)
                {
                    canDiv=canDiv+1;
                }
            
            }
           return canDiv;
       }
```

** Esto es un codigo en bluej**           
2. Esto es un elemento de un arreglo                        
en esta parte final es la que tengo problemas.               
con el código al tratar de encontrar la cantidad divisores sale error en la fórmula for una ayuda porfa no se como hacer que funcione.

Comment: Edité la respuesta con el nuevo código

Comment: Bryan, por favor use los comentarios en vez de editar la respuesta. ¿Qué error le marca al usar `residuo = tamano / vector[indice]`? ¿Y de qué tipo son las variables `tamano` y `vector`?

Comment: Ignore mi última pregunta. Ya lo vi

Comment: Ah y el for está mal planteado. Debería ser `for (indice = 0; indice < vector.size(); indice++)`

Answer (score 2):

Deberías calcular el `residuo` como `tamano % vector[indice]`.

El operador % (modulo) es lo que te da el resto de la división.

Quedaría `residuo = tamano % vector[indice]`